# how to test a mysql connection is available?

Tags: mysql

My program create 5 connections in a pool,but when the program run about 24 hours,the SQLs were executed fail,I think the connections were unavailable,I don't want to adjust the parameter in mysql,I want to modify mysql connection's strategy.When the connection is unavailable,It would close the connection and reconnect again,I didn't find the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL server will drop the session if it stays idle for too long. You have to use `mysql_ping()` periodically or exchange some query with the server to keep it alive. Since you didn't specify the language I cannot help you further.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run a query and see that it succeeds. Often one of these are used:

```
SELECT version()
SELECT 1
SELECT current_time()
```